# Php - loading plugins within class - best method

Tags: php

I have class load.php which handles everything in my app

```
require_once('app/load.php'); 
$micro = New load($mainroute);
$micro->init_plugins();
```

in class in _construnc there is plugins property:

```
$this->plugins = json_decode(file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'micro/'.ROOTPATH.'config/plugins.json'), true);
```

and there is method init_plugins():

```
public function init_plugins() {
    $plugins = $this - > plugins;
    $micro = $this;
    foreach($plugins as $plugin) {
        if ($plugin['active'] == true) {
            include('plugins/'.$plugin['name'].'.php');
        }
    }
}
```

there is sample plugin:

```
require(ABSPATH.'vendor/autoload.php');

use DebugBar\StandardDebugBar;

$debugbar = new StandardDebugBar();
$debugbarRenderer = $debugbar - > getJavascriptRenderer();

$micro - > add_hook('head', 'debug_bar_render_head');
$micro - > add_hook('body_end', 'debug_bar_shutdown');
$micro - > add_hook('body_end', 'debug_bar_render_body');

function debug_bar_render_head() {
    global $debugbarRenderer;
    echo $debugbarRenderer - > renderHead();
}

function debug_bar_render_body() {
    global $debugbarRenderer;
    echo $debugbarRenderer - > render();
}

function debug_bar_shutdown() {
    global $debugbar;
    global $micro;
    $debugbar["messages"] - > addMessage("memory:  ".memory_get_usage());
    $debugbar["messages"] - > addMessage("time: ".$micro - > endtime());
}
```

Firstly, this dont work, i need info where i am mistaking?

I want to everything be in class load, handling for everything including hooks:

```
public function add_hook($hook, $function, $parameters) {
       array_push($this - > micro_hooks[$hook], array('function' = > $function, 'parameters' = > $parameters));
   }

public function do_hook($hook) {
       foreach($this - > micro_hooks[$hook] as $action) {
           call_user_func_array($action['function'], $action['parameters']);
       }
   }

public function dump_hooks() {
       var_dump($this - > micro_hooks);
   }
```

my wanted flow is:

```
     $micro = New load($routes);
     $micro-> init_something();
     $micro-> init_plugins();
```

and i want to plugin creator already have $micro object and to add hooks in there.

My questions are:

1. best aproach for this
2. how to avoid globals if there are other classes in plugins?
3. How to make this to work? It worked when i moved init_plugins() method in out from class, but i want to class handle everything

Comment: what error you're getting in plugin php file?

Comment: 1, 2, 3) Dependency Injection or a Service Container can be used for this so dependencies can be injected directly into the constructor or loaded through the service container. I have used Pimple for this sort of thing, https://packagist.org/packages/pimple/pimple

Comment: \nFatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to a member function renderHead() on a non-object (NULL)' in /home/connect/web/micro.connecting.rs/public_html/plugins/debugbar.php:17